# Convert or edit arima model result

Tags: python, pandas, arima

I have an arima model to make the prediction stored in the model variable.

```
type(model)
pmdarima.arima.arima.ARIMA

model
ARIMA(order=(0, 1, 0), scoring_args={}, seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 12),
  suppress_warnings=True, with_intercept=False)
```

with this value I need to make some removals so that it stays in a way that I can use it elsewhere. EX

```
model
order=(0, 1, 0), seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 12), suppress_warnings=True
```

How can I make this change ? model can be converted to string if needed

Comment: So you want to keep the model but use it on different data? Can you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save your ARIMA model results, you can use the method:

```
model = ARIMA(X, order=(1,1,1))
# save model
model_fit.save('model.pkl')
# load model
loaded = ARIMAResults.load('model.pkl')
```

Jason Brownlee wrote about this on his blog , maybe you can check it:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-arima-time-series-forecasting-model-python/